# Is there a Mass-Temperature relationship for main sequence stars?

Tags: mass, temperature, astrophysics, astronomy, luminosity

When finding relationships between various properties of stars, I frequently find next to nothing on the Mass-Temperature relationship. I, of course, see the Mass-Luminosity and the Luminosity-Temperature relationship. So I wonder, why is there no mass-temperature relationship? Wouldn't it be algebraically viable to come up with this relationship?

As a side note, I'm only looking at main-sequence stars, and excluding the stars that do not fit in the relationship for main-sequence stars, such as giants and white dwarfs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better for astronomy.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because astronomy & astrophysics questions are fully on topic on this site.

Comment: Can't you just use a table from "Astrophysical Quantities"?

Answer (score 1):

For main-sequence stars, the Luminosity is related to the temperature by the expression $L\approx M^{3.5}$. The reason for the 3.5 exponent is because the relationship best fits some stars at $L =  M^3$ up to $L = M^4$. For non-main-sequence stars, you probably need a relationship between density and Luminosity.